# using imread of OpenCV failed when the image is Ok

Tags: opencv, imread

I encountered a problem when I want to read an image using the OpenCV function `imread()`.
The image is Ok and I can show it in the image display software.
But when I use the `imdecode()` to get the image data, the data returns NULL.
I will upload the image and the code and hope some one could help me

```
Mat img = imread(image_name);
if(!img.data) return -1;
```

The image's link is here: http://img3.douban.com/view/photo/raw/public/p2198361185.jpg

PS: The `image_name` is all right. 
    I guess OpenCV cannot decode this image. So is there any way to decode this image using OpenCV?, like add new decode library. By the way, I can read this image using other image library such as freeImage.

Comment: The path to the image might be wrong i.e. `image_name`.

Comment: the image_name is all right， you can test it on your pc
I think it's the image's problem and the opencv can not decode this image.
So is there any thing I can do to make opencv enable to decode this image.

Comment: Can't access image.. 403 error. Well, can you tell exact content in image_name.

Comment: Can you read different images (image types) from the same path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is in `.gif` and it is not supported by OpenCV as of now.

> Note OpenCV offers support for the image formats Windows bitmap (bmp),
>   portable image formats (pbm, pgm, ppm) and Sun raster (sr, ras). With
>   help of plugins (you need to specify to use them if you build yourself
>   the library, nevertheless in the packages we ship present by default)
>   you may also load image formats like JPEG (jpeg, jpg, jpe), JPEG 2000
>   (jp2 - codenamed in the CMake as Jasper), TIFF files (tiff, tif) and
>   portable network graphics (png). Furthermore, OpenEXR is also a
>   possibility.

Source - Click [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html)

You can use something like [this](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg), to perform the conversion.

I was able to load your image using `imread` using this. Also, you can check out [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use the library gif2numpy. It converts a gif image to a numpy image which then can be loaded by OpenCV:

```
import cv2, gif2numpy
np_images, extensions, image_specs = gif2numpy.convert("yourgifimage.gif")
cv2.imshow("np_image", np_images[0])
cv2.waitKey()
```

The library can be found here: https://github.com/bunkahle/gif2numpy It is not dependent on PIL or pillow for this like imageio.

Answer (score -5):

There are two methods to read an image in OpenCV, one is using `Mat` the other one using `IplImage`. I see you have used the former one. You can try with the second argument of `imread` also:

```
image = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file
```

else use `IplImage`

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

IplImage* src = 0;

if( (src = cvLoadImage("filename.jpg",1)) == 0 )
{
    printf("Cannot load file image %s\n", filename);
}
```

If they don't work please check if you have installed libjpeg, libtiff and other dependencies for reading an image in OpenCV.

Hope it would help.

Comment: please, do not advise folks here to use the deprecated c-api. it is no more an option since 2010.