# ImDecode with Gif Images

Tags: python, decode, opencv

I'm getting a none value returned when I try to decode an gif image I've gotten from a URL. Could someone please direct me towards what I'm doing wrong? I haven't worked too much with images so I could really use some advice.

```
gif = "someurlthatgoestoagifimage.gif"
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(gif)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype ="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opencv does not support decoding gif images. You can use other libraries like PIL or imageio to decode or read images.

For example using imageio, you can read a gif image as follows:-

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(gif_url)
img_rgb = imageio.imread(resp.read())
img = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', img)
```

Ref: [How to read gif from url using opencv (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48163539), [using imread of OpenCV failed when the image is Ok](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26600963)